# How do I repair the .Net Framework on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, .net-framework, restore

So I ran spyware doctor and it had a bunch of malware stuff. I clicked "Remove" but failed to create a restore point first. Now my websites running on .net 2.0 as well as visual studio 2008 are not working. My websites running .net 4 and visual studio 2010 are working just fine. I'm assuming I need to restore either .net 2.0/3.5 or something. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Don't blindly delete registry entries without a backup. Also, I've never had any problems with the free Spybot S&D: http://www.safer-networking.org/

Answer (score 3):

One of the MSDN bloggers by the name of Aaron Stebner made a great utility to automate the normally manual process of cleaning out .NET entirely. Normally you would run this utility before re-installing .NET from scratch. I've had to run it on Server 2008 before, so I would assume it works on Vista as well.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160301085724/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx)

Good luck!

Note that this CAN be used to remove embedded versions of .NET, such as 2.0 in Windows 7.

Comment: Comment by @NginUS: I don't have rep to upvote Jeff McJunkin's suggestion about the .NET Cleanup Utility, so I'll just reply.

After hours of uninstalling, reinstalling, rebooting, registry scanning, and manual registry hacking, it's what finally resolved the issues I had with .NET.

Answer (score 0):

I'd run the full installer for [.Net Framework 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0a391abd-25c1-4fc0-919f-b21f31ab88b7&displaylang=en).

I believe as 3.5 before it, 4.0 contains 2.0+ as it expands upon the base of 2.0.

You can try the older installs, but they don't list Windows 7 as supported.

- [.Net Framework 2.0 x86](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0856EACB-4362-4B0D-8EDD-AAB15C5E04F5&displaylang=en)
- [.Net Framework 2.0 x64](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=B44A0000-ACF8-4FA1-AFFB-40E78D788B00&displaylang=en)
- [.Net Framework 3.5 SP1](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe)

Comment: .NET 3.5 did not include 2.0 or previous versions unless you got the all-in-one installer. .NET 4.0 does not include previous versions either. The installers usually do not work on Win7, especially 32-bit installers on a 64-bit OS.

Comment: I linked to the full installers, and I provided both the x86 and x64 installers of 2.0 just for future viewers reference.  The .Net 3.5 one did not specify architecture, the fact that it is 230mb versus the others being 20-50mb, I'm guessing it is a 32/64 combo installer and does have the 2.0/3.0 cumulative updates.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the Windows Resource Checker to verify and repair all system files.  This will include .NET 2.0 on Windows 7.

```
sfc /scannow
```

Comment: tried this, but didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had difficulties running the installers for .NET 3.5 on Win 7/Server 2008 in the past, but have always been successful when using Windows Features. I would try removing it from Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows features on or off, then adding it again.
Are you getting any specific errors in the application event log?

Answer (score 0):

.net 2.0 is the core component in Windows 7 and you cannot uninstall/install it. You can use the command `aspnet_regiis.exe -i` from `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727` to install ASP.NET for IIS 7.5.

Answer (score -1):

None of this worked for me. The only fix was to reinstall Windows 7. To do this:

1. Take the Windows 7 DVD.
2. Uninstall SP1 if your DVD doesn't have SP1.
   If you are unable to uninstall SP1 (you have removed SP1 backup files with clean tool) then right click on `setup.exe` in your Windows DVD -> Properties -> Compatibility -> select Vista SP2. If you don't do this your installer will reject the update.
3. Run the `setup.exe` on the Windows 7 DVD.
4. Follow all steps until it asks for update or install, then click on update. Then the installer will reinstall full Windows 7 without removing of the configuration.